# Bootstrap- How to change the width of the line at the bottom of the nav-tabs?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am wondering how to change the `width` of the line at the bottom of the `nav-tabs`.

On their display page http://getbootstrap.com/components/ where the `nav-tabs` part the line at the bottom stops just before the end of the page. 
But mine is keeping at 100%, wondering how do i change the `length` of that

I tried this but no luck.

```
.nav-tabs {
    border-bottom-width: 50px;
    border-width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I am not getting which width of the line you are talking about?

Comment: Hi sorry, i want to attach a picture but i dont have enough points to do so. But it is the (line)width that is under all the words(tabs), on the top it has the different tabs and the tabs is above a line. And that line extends to the right to the near end of the page(but in my case it extends to the end, i would like to make that shorter)

Comment: show you html code.. you can use http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nobb0nf1/1/ Here you go, the line at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have wrap the ul with a div and set left-right padding on it

```
<div class="navWrapper">
    <ul class = "nav nav-tabs " role="tablist">    
        <li class="active" id="opened"><a href= "#" >Open </a></li>
        <li id="completed"><a href ="completedlisting.html" >Completed </a></li>
        <li id="completed"><a href ="Interestedclientsgeneral.html" >Test</a></li>
        <li  class="dropdown"id="reload33" ><a href= "#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter "></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" id="all">Show all Results</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="thisweek">Posted This week</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="thismonth">Posted This Month</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>



.navWrapper{
    padding:0 15px;
}
```

here is the updated **[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/nobb0nf1/2/)**
hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

.nav-tabs {

```
border-bottom-width: 50px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you are asking like this?

```
 <style>
 body{
    margin:0px;
 }
 footer{
     width:100%;
     border-top:2px solid #f00;
 }
 </style>
```

HTML:

```
 <body>
  <header>
      <ul class="nav-tabs">
        <li>..</li> 
      </ul>
  </header>
  <footer>
      <ul class="nav-tabs">
        <li>..</li> 
      </ul>
  </footer>
  </body>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nobb0nf1/1/ This line at the bottom that extends to the right hand side. to the end of the page, i want to make that shorter

Comment: .nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
instead provide like below
.nav-tabs li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

Answer (score 0):

There is no property available to set border length. The only workaround I found is using linear gradient.

image for reference:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCyJ7.png

```css
.nav-tab {
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 33%,
    rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 33%,
    rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 66%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 66%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%
  );
  border-image-slice: 1;
}
```